# Prisma 2 docker container can't connect MySQL Database container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, prisma

I'm developing Backend server with prisma 2, MySQL, Docker-compose, GraphQL-Yoga server

My OS is Windows 10, docker compose use debian-openssl-1.1.x

problem is prisma 2 container can't connect MySQL container

- docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.19
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
  prisma:
    links:
      - mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    container_name: prisma
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    build:
      context: back/prisma
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      MYSQL_URL: $${MYSQL_URL}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - /app/prisma
  backend:
    links:
      - mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    build:
      context: back
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      MYSQL_URL: $${MYSQL_URL}
      FRONTEND_URL: $${FRONTEND_URL}
    volumes:
      - ./back:/app
      - ./back/node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - ./back/prisma:/app/prisma
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    build:
      context: front
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      BACKEND_URL: $${BACKEND_URL}
    volumes:
      - ./front:/app
      - ./front/node_modules:/app/node_modules
```

- .env

```
MYSQL_URL="mysql://root:prisma@mysql:3306/prisma"
BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:4000
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
MYSQL_DATABASE:"prisma"
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:"prisma"
```

-schema.prisma

```
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "debian-openssl-1.1.x"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

- .env in prisma folder

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:prisma@mysql:3306/prisma"
```

when i run docker-compose (docker-compose up), prisma container (prisma 2 studio) show this logs

```
Error in Prisma Client request: 

Error: 
Invalid `prisma.user.count()` invocation:

Authentication failed against database server at `mysql`, the provided database credentials for `root` are not valid.

Please make sure to provide valid database credentials for the database server at `mysql`.
    at PrismaClientFetcher.request (/root/.cache/prisma/studio/app/runtime/index.js:1:52273)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USb4L.png)

I think this error occurred because MySQL container has a password different from MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD which I wrote in the doctor-compose.yml.
But, i think there seems to be no problem with the setup, why is this error happening?

And if i did not set up MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, what is the default password value generated by MySQL container?

I searched for days to find the answer to this problem, but I could not get the answer. please give me some advices. thank you

Comment: Hi, are you sure you need double Dollar signs($$)?  I know only this ${VAR_NAME} in docker-compose file

Comment: can you check once containers are created that you have the right env vars in the mysql container? You can check that via `docker inspect <MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME>`

Comment: @akazuko Thank you, i finally found solution.  The cause was a problem with the .env file and the dollar text should be used only once.

Comment: @NMathar Thank you, you're right. $ must be written only once

Comment: @sdy can you share the repo if it is open source,
if not possible share the dockerFile of prisma

Comment: @sdy another question. what is your database string of in env file? mine is `DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:prisma@mysql:3306/prisma"` but I am not suew it is right or not.

Comment: @Ashik my code exactly same yours, check out this documentation link [link](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-connectors/mysql/)

Comment: @sdy but I am getting same error you got before. `Authentication failed against database server at `mysql`, the provided database credentials for `root` are not valid`

Comment: even I hardcode all the values in docker-comose file

Comment: I know you already solved the problem, but for anybody else who may find this: I had the same error when trying to connect, and I realized that I had to percent-encode my password and it fixed the issue. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding